# What is the logic behind this double function call with recursion?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Where I currently have the console logs, `countdown` seems to count down from 10 to 1 (this makes sense) but then after this, `way` seems to add 15 to the final result of `countdown` 9 times, but for this to happen, I'd imagine that after each `countdown` loop, `way` is called, but that each keeps track of its own `value`? Any clarification about the Why and When of this logic would be helpful - Thanks!

```js
var countdown = function(value) {
  value = value - 1;
  
  if (value == 0) {
    return value;
  }
  
  console.log("loop 1 " + value);
  return way(countdown(value));
};

function way(value) {
  value = value + 15;
  console.log(value);
  return value;
}

countdown(10);
```

Comment: `value` is a *parameter* to both functions. It's not a global value.

Comment: Can you post the console output to clarify?

Comment: Run this with a debugger and what what happens.  Especially attend to the location of `value`.  Failing that, put in a couple of useful `console.log` statements to track execution flow.

Comment: What is this code good for aside from trying to exhaust stack size for nothing? ;)

Comment: Please learn to use semicolons. ASI often produces unexpected results (it's not the issue here, though).

Comment: Apart from a few edge cases no semicolons is fine though I like to try use them

Comment: @user7951676 I've seen some questions where the problem was due to one of those edge cases. I think it's best to just avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this recursive code, it's easiest to follow the program counter:

```
function way (value) {
  value=value +15
  console.log(value)
  return value
}

countdown = function(value) {
  value = value-1
  if (value == 0) {
       return value;
  }
  console.log("loop 1 " + value)

  return way(
      countdown(value));
};

countdown(10);
```

- Start countdown with 10
- value > 0 so run `way(countdown(9))` //note: countdown is executed first.
- Countdown runs with 9
- value > 0 so run `way(countdown(8))` //note: countdown is executed first.
- ...
- ...
- ...
- value  == 0, return 0 (in countdown): execute `way`
- way returns 0 + 15
- way returns 15 + 15
- way .... etc.

As fora clarification why this logic would be helpful; I think there is a lesson to be learned here.

Basically there are 2 relevant function-call positions when applying recursion:

1. positioned *before* recursive call
2. positioned *after* recursive call

I will leave it as an exercise of why this has any relevance.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above `value` is a local variable in either function and thus always bound to the scope of either function. It doesn't actually contribute to confusion aside from expecting too much complexity there. ;)

The behaviour arises from `countdown()` being called recursively and calling `way()` has to wait until recursive calls for countdown() are returning. But that's not happening until `countdown()`'s recursion has stopped at value 0 to be returned eventually. After that `countdown()` isn't invoked ever again, but since `countdown()` was invoked recursively and this is bubbling up through all invocations of `countdown()` there are multiple calls for `way()` with the result returned from the `countdown()` called at end which in turn was calling `way()` with result of `countdown()` etc. ... ok, got a bit confused here myself.

Since `value` isn't required to be that complex it might help to eliminate it for reducing code:

```
function countdown(value) {
  if ( value == 1 ) { return 0; } // bail out condition

  console.log("loop 1 " + value)
  return way( countdown( value - 1 ) );
};

function way( value ) {
  console.log(value);
  return value + 15;
}

countdown(10);
```

`way()` is of no relevance to the recursion and thus might be substituted:

```
function countdown(value) {
  if ( value == 1 ) { return 0; } // bail out condition

  console.log("loop 1 " + value)
  return countdown( value - 1 ) + 15;
};

countdown(10);
```

Due to recursion this code is diving into stack 9 frames deep. And then it is bubbling up stack returning the result of every passed frame increased by another 15 prior to bubbling up further on.

So actually, there is only one recursion.

Answer (score 0):

At first, the code starts executing your first call to `countdown` with argument `value=10`

1. Stack: []
2. Execute `countdown(10)`
3. Stack: [`countdown(10)`]
4. Then execute `way(countdown(9))`, and to execute this, JS first evaluates `countdown(9)`
5. Stack: [`countdown(10)`, `countdown(9)`, ] and so on, you can imagine, until you reach `countdown(0)`, then start popping out from the stack call.
6. First stack call resolved, `countdown(0) = 0`, then call `way(0)`, the console logs `0+15`, then `countdown(0)` eventually returns `15`, then pop from stack `countdown(1)` which is equal to `way(countdown(0))`, which is `way(15)`, then prints out `30`, and so on...

Hope this is clear enough